# Refresh Fancybox Every 5 seconds

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, symfony

I have a fancybox that is loaded in a iframe.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#prodacom_aerohivebundle_aerohivessid_ssid_inschakelen").fancybox({
            type: "iframe",
            href: "http://localhost/aerohive_ap/web/app_dev.php/queue"
        });
    });
</script>
```

This is working fine but now i want to refresh the iframe every 5 seconds without closing the iframe/fancybox.

Is this possible ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:-

```
        setInterval(function () {
            document.querySelector('.fancybox-wrap iframe').contentWindow.location.reload();
        },5000);
```

Answer (score 0):

As per a related answer on SO

```
$.fancybox.update(); // update

setInterval(function () {
    $.fancybox.update();
}, 5000); // calls update every 5 seconds
```

Comment: i don't think this will refresh the iframe data.. it will just adjust the fancybox based on screen size..